# In table of contents, label sections in Chapter 1 as 1, 2, ... instead of 1.1, 1.2, ...

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.0em]{\bfseries}{2.5em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[4.5em]{}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]
\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}

\chapter{Chapter III}
\section{Section III.1}

\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```

For example, the label for Section II.1 should be "1" instead of "II.1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is just for display in the table of contents, you can use the "above-code" argument of `\dottedcontents` to strip the leading roman numeral off the section number as stored in `\thecontentslabel` as follows:

```
\def\stripleading#1.#2{#2}
\dottedcontents{section}[4.5em]{\xdef\thecontentslabel{\expandafter\stripleading
\thecontentslabel}}{3.5em}{0.75pc}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\normalfont}
{\itshape \partname~\thepart}{1.0em}
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\dottedcontents{chapter}[3.0em]{\bfseries}{2.5em}{0pc}

\def\stripleading#1.#2{#2}
\dottedcontents{section}[4.5em]{\xdef\thecontentslabel{\expandafter\stripleading\thecontentslabel}}{3.5em}{0.75pc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]
\part{Part I}

\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{}

\chapter{Chapter I}
\section{Section I.1}

\chapter{Chapter II}
\section{Section II.1}
\section{Section II.2}

\chapter{Chapter III}
\section{Section III.1}

\stopcontents[parts]

\end{document}
```